# Safari 8.0 Full Screen Shortcut Not Working

Tags: safari, macos, shortcut

After updating to OS X Yosemite (Public Release), Safari and several other applications stopped recognising <kbd>⌃</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> as the shortcut to enter Full Screen. I can use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to enter Full Screen in Chrome, but not in Safari.

The shortcut worked when I was using OS X Yosemite Beta and Yosemite Beta 2. How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know about Yosemite, but on my Mavericks it is the

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>cmd</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd>

The cmd-shif-F brings the search window.